# Expression API throws exception: variable 'x' of type 'x' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression, expression-trees

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        ContrivedComparer.Compare<Person>(person => person.Name == "Calvin");
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ContrivedComparer
{
    // this likely looks highly ill-advised out of context but this is contrived.
    public static readonly object comparatePerson = new Person { Name = "Ted" };

    public static void Compare<TComparate>(Expression<Func<TComparate, bool>> predicate) 
    {
        if (predicate.Compile()((TComparate)comparatePerson)) return;

        var expression = (BinaryExpression)predicate.Body;

        var actual = Expression.Lambda(expression.Left).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
        var expected = Expression.Lambda(expression.Right).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
    }
}
```

I expect `actual` to have the same value as the left operand and for `expected` to have the same value as the the right operand.

However, this code throws an `InvalidOperationException` with the following message:

> variable 'person' of type 'Person' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined.

How can I resolve this exception?

Comment: What are `actual` and `expected` supposed to end up being?

Comment: @Jon Sorry if I was unclear Jon. I updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't passing the parameter to the lambda that you're creating the second time, the way that you are the first time.  You need to indicate that there is a parameter when constructing the lambda and pass in the value when invoking it.

```
public static void Compare<TComparate>(Expression<Func<TComparate, bool>> predicate)
{
    if (predicate.Compile()((TComparate)comparatePerson)) return;

    var expression = (BinaryExpression)predicate.Body;

    var actual = Expression.Lambda(expression.Left, predicate.Parameters)
        .Compile().DynamicInvoke(comparatePerson);
    var expected = Expression.Lambda(expression.Right, predicate.Parameters)
        .Compile().DynamicInvoke(comparatePerson);
}
```